# z-index does not work on li navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I use the navbar bootstrap (.navbar-inverse, .navbar-static-top) and I would like to apply a z-index to a particular "li" so that it passes over a div opacity to 0.5. (the "be stronger" "li")

http://www.bootply.com/132530

Problem: even with a z-index and position: relative, "li" is not displayed over the div.

I tried to apply this css to each parent li, one by one, but it only works for the last parent: div.navbar

```
<div style="z-index:8888" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
```

works, but I do not want to show all the navbar

Is it possible to show only this "li" ?

thank you in advance

Comment: position:absolute is required in this case

Comment: It makes sense for it to work applying it to the div since the top level div is in the same stacking order as the fixed positioned translucent div. What are you trying to achieve? I think this can be done with a different approach if you can explain exactly what you want to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458090/weird-z-index-issue-floating-list-items-not-showing-above-heading hope this link will be help full

Comment: @Abudayah Can you provide an example from the link given from the OP? I don't see how this can be achieved with the current approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.
You will need to change your HTML markup in order to do that.

"If an element B sits on top of element A, a child element of element A can never be higher than element B."

[source](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)